# tls handshake timeout when run docker container after a pptpd vpn server

Tags: docker, ssl, tls1.2

How to reproduce it:

1. create a PPTP server
2. connect the PPTP server from your host
3. run a Debian docker container in your host
4. run this command in the Docker container: curl --insecure  -v -i  https://www.google.com
5. get the result below:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.221.238...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (216.58.221.238) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to google.com:443 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

This issue won't happen, if you do one of those below:

1. Do not use PPTP server, and run curl in a docker container
2. Do not use docker container, and run curl in your host which after a pptpd server
3. Do not connect to https://www.google.com, but to https://www.wordpress.com in the same VPN and docker condition

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a PPTP MTU problem.
I have to set ppp0's mtu to a lower value to prevent this problem.